# How can I replace a line of text in a file with a single command when the line contains a variable?

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I have a script called **script.sh** which has the contents

```
export HELLO=$WORLD
```

I want to change it using a single command to

```
export HELLO=${WORLD:2:3}
```

I'm attempting to use the sed command but i'm new to linux and can't quite get it right. Here's what I have

```
sed -i 's/export HELLO=$WORLD/export HELLO=${WORLD:2:3}' script.sh
```

How should this line be written to replace the text correctly?

Comment: Great job on the question with input, expected output and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed a `/` at the very end:

```
sed -i 's/export HELLO=$WORLD/export HELLO=${WORLD:2:3}/' script.sh
                                                       ^
                                       this / is missing
```

Comment: Thank you! It's always something simple.

Answer (score 0):

The $ is a special symbol that means end of line, also as @yvesonline points out you are missing the trailing /.  This is how I would do it:

```
sed -i 's/\(export HELLO=\$\)\(WORLD\)/\1{\2:2:3}/' script.sh
```